# Read patterns Simple DSL using Python SLY

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, sly

I try to create simple DSL with Python [SLY](https://sly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sly.html) . But, I can't get the result as I expected because the parser can't read it properly. So here the code :

Lexer

```
from sly import Lexer

class ConfigLexer(Lexer):
  tokens = { ANIMALS, BLOOD, SKIN, BREATHE, ANIMAL_NAME, VALUE, ASSIGN }

  ignore    = " \t\r"
  ignore_newline = r'\n+'

  ANIMALS       = "ANIMALS"
  BLOOD         = "BLOOD"
  SKIN          = "SKIN"
  BREATHE       = "BREATHE"
  ANIMAL_NAME   = r'\{[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\}'
  VALUE         = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_,.: ]*'
  ASSIGN        = r'\='
```

Parser

```
from sly import Parser

class ConfigParser(Parser):
    tokens = ConfigLexer.tokens

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = dict()
        self.dict_attribute = dict()
        self.animal_name = ""
    
    @_("ANIMALS animaldetails")
    def animals(self, p):
        pass
    
    @_("ANIMAL_NAME animalnamedetails")
    def animaldetails(self, p):
        self.animal_name = p.ANIMAL_NAME.replace("{", "").replace("}","")
        if self.animal_name not in self.config:
            self.config[self.animal_name] = self.dict_attribute
    
    @_("BLOOD ASSIGN VALUE")
    def animalnamedetails(self, p):
        if p.BLOOD not in self.dict_attribute:
            self.dict_attribute[p.BLOOD] = p.VALUE
    
    @_("SKIN ASSIGN VALUE")
    def animalnamedetails(self, p):
        if p.SKIN not in self.dict_attribute:
            self.dict_attribute[p.SKIN] = p.VALUE
    
    @_("BREATHE ASSIGN VALUE")
    def animalnamedetails(self, p):
        if p.BREATHE not in self.dict_attribute:
            self.dict_attribute[p.BREATHE] = p.VALUE
    
    def get_config(self):
        return self.config
```

but when I run it.

```
import json
import ConfigLexer
import ConfigParser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lexer = ConfigLexer()
    parser = ConfigParser()
    long_string = """ANIMALS
{MAMMALS}
BLOOD = WARM
SKIN = FUR
BREATHE = LUNGS
{FISH}
BLOOD = COLD
SKIN = SCALY
BREATHE = GILLS"""
    result = parser.parse(lexer.tokenize(long_string))
    cfg = parser.get_config()
    data_json = json.dumps(cfg, indent=3)
    print(data_json)
```

as I expected, the result would be like this.

```
data_json = {
'MAMMALS': {'BLOOD': 'WAMR': 'SKIN': 'FUR OR HAIR', 'BREATHE': 'LUNGS'},
'FISH': {'BLOOD': 'COLD', 'SKIN': 'SCALY', 'BREATHE': 'GILLS'}
}
```

but I only get something like this.

```
data_json = {
   'MAMMALS': {
      'BLOOD': 'WARM'
   }
}
```

[image: and has an error on SKIN token.]

result of executing :

```
sly: Syntax error at line 1, token=SKIN
{
   "MAMMALS": {
      "BLOOD": "WARM"
   }
}
```

I guess I have to edit the Parser, but I can't think how, and would appreciate any pointers you can give me.

Comment: Please include any text (such as the result of executing) as text, not as images. Images are impossible to copy and paste, and are often hard to read, particularly for people whose vision is in some way impaired.

Comment: @rici sorry, thank You for the advice. I already edited the questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have non-terminals named `animals`, `animaldetails`, and `animalnameddetails`, in plural, which would normally lead one to expect that the grammar for each of them would allow a sequence of things. But they don't. Each of these categories parses a single thing. You've implemented the singular, and although it's named in plural, there's no repetition.

That this was not your intent is evident from your example, which does have multiple sections and multiple attributes in each section. But since the grammar only describes one attribute and value, the second one is a syntax error.

Traditionally, grammars will implement sequences with pairs of non-terminals; a singular non-terminal which describes a single thing, and a plural non-terminal which describes how lists are formed (simple concatenation, or separated by punctuation). So you might have:

```
file: sections
sections: empty
        | sections section
section: category attributes
settings: empty
        | settings setting
setting: attribute '=' value
```

You probably should also look fora description of how to manage semantic values. Storing intermediate results in class members, as you do, works only when the grammar doesn't allow nesting, which is relatively unusual. It's a technique which will almost always get you into trouble. The semantic actions of each production should manage these values:

- A singular object syntax should create *and return* a representation of the object.
- A *plural→empty* production should create and return a representation of an empty collection.
- Similarly, a production of the form *things→ things thing* should append the new thing to the aggregate of things, and then return the augmented aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers...

```
from json import dumps

from sly import Lexer, Parser

class MyLexer(Lexer):
    tokens = {ANIMALS, ANIMAL_NAME, BLOOD, SKIN, BREATHE, ASSIGN, ASSIGN_VALUE}
    ignore = ' \t'

    ANIMALS = r'ANIMALS'
    BLOOD = r'BLOOD'
    SKIN = r'SKIN'
    BREATHE = r'BREATHE'

    ASSIGN = r'='
    ASSIGN_VALUE = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'

    @_(r'\{[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\}')
    def ANIMAL_NAME(self, t):
        t.value = str(t.value).lstrip('{').rstrip('}')
        return t

    @_(r'\n+')
    def NEWLINE(self, t):
        self.lineno += t.value.count('\n')


class MyParser(Parser):
    tokens = MyLexer.tokens

    def __init__(self):
        self.__config = {}

    def __del__(self):
        print(dumps(self.__config, indent=4))

    @_('ANIMALS animal animal')
    def animals(self, p):
        pass

    @_('ANIMAL_NAME assignment assignment assignment')
    def animal(self, p):
        if p.ANIMAL_NAME not in self.__config:
            self.__config[p.ANIMAL_NAME] = {}
        animal_name, *assignments = p._slice
        for assignment in assignments:
            assignment_key, assignment_value = assignment.value
            self.__config[p.ANIMAL_NAME][assignment_key] = assignment_value

    @_('key ASSIGN ASSIGN_VALUE')
    def assignment(self, p):
        return p.key, p.ASSIGN_VALUE

    @_('BLOOD', 'SKIN', 'BREATHE')
    def key(self, p):
        return p[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lexer = MyLexer()
    parser = MyParser()
    text = '''ANIMALS
{MAMMALS}
BLOOD = WARM
SKIN = FUR
BREATHE = LUNGS
{FISH}
BLOOD = COLD
SKIN = SCALY
BREATHE = GILLS
'''
    parser.parse(lexer.tokenize(text))
```

Output:

```
{
    "MAMMALS": {
        "BLOOD": "WARM",
        "SKIN": "FUR",
        "BREATHE": "LUNGS"
    },
    "FISH": {
        "BLOOD": "COLD",
        "SKIN": "SCALY",
        "BREATHE": "GILLS"
    }
}
```